# Deinit never called on custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Hello I have a `UIViewController` which has 4 custom `UIView`. Deinit function inside `UIViewController` is called when I change the rootViewController but doesn't called inside custom `UIView`. Therefore, It persists in memory after I change root controller. If I call `myCustomView.removeFromSuperView()` inside ViewControllers `Deinit` function, It works. However, I don't wanna write it everytime in a viewcontrollers so I want to write it inside custom UIView class but `Deinit` inside Custom UIView never get called.

How I declare custom view:

```
lazy var myCustomView = WelcomeScreenButtonView(text: getLabelText(key: SUPPORTEDSERVICES), imageName: "img")
let firstStackView = UIStackView()

override func viewDidLoad(){
//I put it inside a UIStackView
firstStackView.addArrangedSubview(myCustomView)
view.addSubView(firstStackView)
}
deinit{
//If I do it like this, It works but I don't wanna call it in here
myCustomView.removeFromSuperView()
}
```

My Custom UIView Class:

```
class WelcomeScreenButtonView: UIView {

lazy var label = UILabel()
private lazy var logoImage = UIImageView()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupUI()
    setupConstraints()
}
required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
deinit {
    //This one never get called
    print("WelcomeScreen Button Deinited")
    removeFromSuperview()
}
}
```

**EDIT:** If I change my custom view to UIView() (all other codes are same). It is deallocating. Therefore, I guess I have something to do with custom UIView class.

Comment: If a view is in the view hierarchy, its superview retains it and it cannot be released from memory.

Comment: Something you are doing is causing a reference cycle which is preventing the custom view from being deallocated.

Comment: I'm not sure about that because I'm not doing anything extreme. Just add target to these buttons. What can cause that?